# Questions by views on new user page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

When I'm on the user page's `Summary` tab, I can sort a user's "top 5" answers by three criteria: `votes activity newest`:

[image]

If I go to that user's full list of answers, I am presented with the same three options:
[image]

If I go to a user's full list of QUESTIONS, I am presented with four options: `votes activity newest views`
[image]

So why, pray tell, would I only be allowed to sort the `Summary` tab's "top 5" questions by the first three criteria? Shouldn't I be able to sort by views just like I can on the actual tab, as monstrously shown below:

[image]

Edit: So I was just frustrated by this again today, and went to see if someone had reported it. I couldn't find it by searching, but I thought "on the off chance that I've already asked for this, I'll look again" and sure enough it was here. I'd really like to see this. It's got to be pretty easy to do; it already exists on a different tab!

Comment: `+1` but I've reached my vote limit...